# how to implement a website with cloud storage?

Tags: html, google-app-engine, web, google-cloud-platform

I want to implement a website interface, where the website consist of multiple users and one admin , each user can upload/ download data to the website with some privileges to each user. the data should stored in a cloud such as google-cloud.

i am planning to implement the website using html ? but how can i connect the google-cloud with my html pages?

thanx

Comment: SO is not the site to ask questions on how to implement an entire application. If you have a specific question regarding your code as implement this site, feel free to ask it here.

Comment: look up "google app engine" for real, follow the tutorial. It's EXACTLY what you want.

Comment: @patrice according to ur suggestion, i have not to implement the page first using html.. i can program it directly using google app engine.

thank u .. it is good idea

Comment: @jsve my question was how to connect the html page to the cloud storage, so i was looking for a suggested code.. then patrice suggested another method which more reliable than my method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the Google App Engine is exactly what you want. Using [Java servlets and Javascript](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/introduction), using [python](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/introduction), using [php](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/gettingstarted/introduction), or using [Go](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/gettingstarted/introduction), this can be achieved.

And the App Engine gives you a bunch of solutions for storage ([cloud storage](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlecloudstorageclient/) and
[blobstore](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/)).